# .deb package not found in Docker container, even when installing from within the container

Tags: apt, dpkg, docker

I want to install the `globalprotect` VPN client in an Ubuntu docker image. I have downloaded the deb files, and have manged to successfully install it on the host (also Ubuntu) like so:

`sudo apt install ~/docker/ashutepconnect/assets/myvpn/GlobalProtect_deb-6.0.4.1-28.deb`

and I can connect using `globalprotect connect --portal [portal]`.

Moving on to the image, this is my dockerfile: (located in `~/docker/ashutepconnect/`)

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Ashkan <ashkan.arabim@gmail.com>

# Skip prompts
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update packages
RUN apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade -y

# Install packages
RUN apt-get install -y neofetch ssh
COPY assets /assets
RUN apt-get install -y /assets/myvpn/GlobalProtect_deb-6.0.4.1-28.deb
# note: you must log into the vpn when you start this
```

and it successfully builds using `docker build -t ashutepconnect:1.3 .`.

BUT, when I start a container with the image and try using `globalprotect`, it's not found. Inside the container, when I try `dpkg -L globalprotect`, and I get the following:

```
/.
/opt
/opt/paloaltonetworks
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/pre_exec_gps.sh
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwaheap.so.4
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/gpa.service
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwaapi.so.4.3.2384.0
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwaresource.so
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/PanGPS
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/PanGPA
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/PanGpHipMp
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/gpshow.sh
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwalocal.so.4.3.2384.0
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/sign
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/sign/PanGPS-sha384.sig
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/sign/globalprotect-sha384.sig
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/sign/gp-public.pem
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/sign/PanGpHipMp-sha384.sig
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/sign/PanGpHip-sha384.sig
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/sign/PanGPA-sha384.sig
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwautils.so.4.3.2384.0
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/globalprotect
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/gpd
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/license.cfg
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/PanMSInit.sh
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/gp_support.sh
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/PanGpHip
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/gpd.service
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/globalprotect.1.gz
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwautils.so.4
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwalocal.so
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwalocal.so.4
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwaapi.so
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwaapi.so.4
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwautils.so
/opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/libwaheap.so
```

which is exactly what I get from the host. I can even remove the package by `apt remove globalprotect` in the container and reinstall it with the files from `/asset`.

The only difference I noticed was that in the host, `ls /usr/bin/ | grep globalprotect` returns `globalprotect`, but the same command in the container doesn't return anything. Why isn't the package binary getting added to `/usr/bin`?

Comment: "`ls /usr/bin/ | grep globalprotect` returns `globalprotect`" ... but the list of files in the package that you show us doesn't have anything in `/usr/bin`, so I'd investigate how that file came to be in `/usr/bin` in your host system. Maybe you created a link or copied it there and forgot about it? Check the maintainer scripts of the package - `dpkg-deb --ctrl-tarfile /path/to/deb | tar xv` and look at the `postinst` file if present.